# File not opening with OpenTextFile in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, listbox

Here am trying to open the file by selecting in listbox in html contains txt file names like hello.txt.

Path am giving like this "E:\DragableExample\Documents\"+selected"

here vale of "selected" will be hello.txt

```
function savedload()
{
var doc = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var dpt = document.getElementById("sltrtcnty");
var selected=  dpt.options[dpt.selectedIndex].value;
var txt = doc.OpenTextFile("E:\\DragableExample\\Documents\\"+selected,1,true);
alert(txt);
var row=txt.ReadAll();  
document.all.mySaveModel.value = row;
var str = document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value;
myDiagram.model = go.Model.fromJson(document.all.mySavedModel.value );
myDiagram.model.undoManager.isEnabled = true;
doc.quit(0);
```

}

Comment: first you can check what value holds by selected variable using alert()

Comment: selected variable will have hello.txt

Comment: did you get any error messages

Comment: No in alert am getting simple hello.txt selcted form listbox in html

Comment: did you check alert(row) after the ReadAll()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jQuery.get() to Read Text File

```
jQuery.get('file.txt', function(data) {
   alert(data);
   //process text file line by line
   $('#div').html(data.replace('n','<br />'));
});
```